# Laravel redirecciones en un controlador

Tags: laravel

Tengo un controlador que recibe una llamada por `post`, con unos datos en la petición (`$request`). Necesito que ese controlador haga un cálculo y luego redireccione a otro controlador, enviando los mismos datos que recibió en el cuerpo de la petición. He probado lo siguiente:

```
public function destino1(Request $request)
{
    dump ("DESTINO 1: ", $request);
    return redirect()->route('operatorDestino2')->with($request);
}

public function destino2(Request $request)
{
    dd ("DESTINO 2: ", $request);
}
```

También he probado con el método `withInput()`, en lugar de `with()`.

Sin embargo, esto no funciona. Lo que obtengo es una excepción del tipo `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`, lo que me da a entender que el `redirect()` no se entiende con el método `post`, sino que redirecciona sólo por `get`. Eso imposibilita pasar el cuerpo de la petición.

¿Hay en Laravel alguna alternativa para saltar de un controlador a otro pasando la `$request` original que ha recibido el primer controlador?

Comment: ¿qué hace el segundo método/controlador que no pueda hacer el primero?

Comment: Bueno. En el ejemplo, he tratado de simplificar. Realmente, el primer controlador debe leer uno de los datos de la petición y, según su valor, reenviar todo el cuerpo de la petición a uno u otro controlador. Así, en el primer método, la petición solo estaría, digamos, "de paso" hacia su destino definitivo, y es en este primer método donde se determina ese destino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos en términos simples que por convenciones de diseño es incorrecto llamar a un controlador desde otro controlador, por lo cual debes buscar una solución que permita que ambos controladores se comuniquen sin llamarse mutuamente.

Teniendo en cuenta que no tenemos suficiente información sobre lo que realizan los diferentes controladores, planteo una solución genérica que permite abstraer el manejo de la información para evitar el error de llamar a uno u otro controlador.

La opción es crear una capa de servicio, a la cual se le puede pasar la información desde el primer controlador y la cual finalmente será la que procese toda la información y realice los cálculos necesarios, etc.

```
class FirstController extends Controller 
{
    // el servicio puede ser inyectado según la necesidad o llamado directamente

    public function getData(Request $request)
    {
        // recibir información y pasarla al servicio
        MyService::processData($request->all());
    }
}
```

Servicio:

```
class MyService
{
    public function processData($data)
    {
        // hacer cálculos
        // determinar qué hacer según los valores recibidos o cálculos realizados
        // llamar otros métodos del servicio, o procesar toda la información en este método
    }

    // de ser necesario, los otros controladores pueden utilizar este servicio también para almacenar o buscar información
}
```